# How to send PAXOS token which has not transfer method?

Tags: erc-20, contract-deployment, sendtransaction, usdt

I'm new in Ethereum contracts. I could implement sending [USDT](https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7) tokens through [web3.php](https://github.com/sc0Vu/web3.php), and everything work well. Now, I want to add [PAXOS](https://etherscan.io/token/0x8e870d67f660d95d5be530380d0ec0bd388289e1) and send such tokens through my system. But I found there is not any `transfer()` method for PAXOS like what is in USDT contract.
May you help me please and say what is the way to send PAXOS?

Answer (score 2):

It **does** have a `transfer` function, you just don't see in the contract because the author has used the *Upgradable Contract* design-pattern, which (as implied by its name) allows him/her to upgrade the contract.

Here are a few more examples of ERC20-Token contracts which were implemented the same way:

- [BUSD Token](https://etherscan.io/address/0x4Fabb145d64652a948d72533023f6E7A623C7C53#code)
- [AMPL Token](https://etherscan.io/address/0xD46bA6D942050d489DBd938a2C909A5d5039A161#code)
- [USDC Token](https://etherscan.io/address/0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48#code)
- [REP  Token](https://etherscan.io/address/0x1985365e9f78359a9B6AD760e32412f4a445E862#code)
- [TUSD Token](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000085d4780B73119b644AE5ecd22b376#code)
- [SNX  Token](https://etherscan.io/address/0xC011A72400E58ecD99Ee497CF89E3775d4bd732F#code)
- [JRT  Token](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8A9C67fee641579dEbA04928c4BC45F66e26343A#code)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it uses some sort of a proxy. They claim to be ERC20 compatible so they have to have `transfer` function - it just might not be listed due to their proxy pattern.

I'm not familiar with how their system works but if I understand correctly the even say that it's not so obvious in their github:

> Because the implementation address in the proxy is a private variable,
>   verifying that this is the proxy being used requires reading contract
>   storage directly. This can be done using a mainnet node, such as
>   infura, by pasting the network address in truffle-config.js and
>   running

Here's the proxy: https://etherscan.io/address/0x8e870d67f660d95d5be530380d0ec0bd388289e1#code
Here's their contract details (according to them): https://github.com/paxosglobal/pax-contracts